# Select2 dynamic dropdowns with templating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, jquery-select2

Trying to work out how to use the select2 templating function with a dynamic select2 dropdown to also show the extra data in a JSON response

My question does not relate to how to create the HTML template formating (I have already figured that out). I want to know how to make templating work when loading remote data - at the moment the remote data load function overwrites the templating...

Below is an example of what I mean by "templating" the result. I want to be able to specific the formating for the "otherData" and "extraData" fields

[image: Example of templating]

Current example data format (used by the code below that does not work with templating)

> {"12":"DASGDSA67"}

Proposed example data (as JSON with extra data)

> {"id":"12","value":"DASGDSA67","otherData":"Brunswick","extraData":"Heads"}

View (Javascript)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".company2").select2();
    $(".location2").select2({
        templateResult: formatState
    });
});

$(".company2").select2().on('change', function() {
var $company2 = $('.company2');
$.ajax({
    url:"../api/locations/" + $company2.val(),
    type:'GET',
    success:function(data) {
        var $location2 = $(".location2");
        $location2.empty();
        $.each(data, function(value, key) {
            $location2.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(key));
        }); 
        $location2.select2();
    }
});
}).trigger('change');

function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
      var $state = $(
         '<h1>' + state.element.value() + '</h1>' + '<p>' + state.element.otherData() + '</p>'
      );
  return $state;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is missing some information. What are you expecting the result to look like?

Comment: @KevinBrown I have added an example image

Comment: An image isn't really useful here, especially the one from the example. Perhaps if you gave us some example markup that you were looking to display (and where the `otherData` and `extraData` would be) someone could help.

Comment: @KevinBrown my question does not relate to how to create the HTML template formating (I have already figured that out). I want to know how to make templating work when loading remote data - at the moment the remote data load function overwrites the templating...

Comment: @KevinBrown any more ideas?